# How do I replace part of the value of attributes for a set of elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex, replace

I am trying to replace a series of 'for' attributes of labels based on their current contents.

The application is using AJAX to add an item to an invoice without refreshing the page.  Upon receiving notification of a successful item add, my script should replace all the labels in the form whose 'for' attribute ends with '-new' with the same attribute minus the '-new' and adding ('-' + itemValue), where itemValue is the item Id of the invoice item that was added.

I know how to select all the labels I want to change at once:

```
jQuery('label[for$=new]')
```

I know how to get their 'for' attribute:

```
jQuery('label[for$=new]').attr('for')
```

I tried the JavaScript replace method:

```
jQuery('label[for$=new]').attr('for').replace(/-new/,itemValue)
```

But that appears to select each label's 'for' attribute, replace the text, and pass the replaced text back (to nothing), since I don't know how to identify the labels that have the 'for' attribute I want to replace.

Here's some sample HTML:

```
<form id="InvoiceItemsForm-1" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" name="InvoiceItemsForm-1" onsubmit="return false">
<div id="InvoiceItem-new-1" class="InvoiceItem">
<label for="InvoiceItemNumber-new">New Invoice Item Number: </label>
<input id="InvoiceItemNumber-new" class="InvoiceItemNumber" type="text" value="" name="InvoiceItemNumber-new">
<label for="InvoiceItemDescription-new">Item Description: </label>
<input id="InvoiceItemDescription-new" class="InvoiceItemDescription" type="text" value="" name="InvoiceItemDescription-new">
<label for="InvoiceItemAmount-new">Item Amount: </label>
<input id="InvoiceItemAmount-new" class="InvoiceItemAmount" type="text" value="" name="InvoiceItemAmount-new">
<input id="addInvoiceItem-1" width="25" type="image" height="25" src="/payapp/images/greenplus.th.png" alt="Add New Invoice Item" onclick="addInvoiceItemButtonPushed(this)" value="invoiceItem">
</div>
<button id="CloseInvoice-1" onclick="closeInvoice(this)" type="button">Close Invoice</button>
</form>
```

Once I get this to work, I'm going to replace all the ids for all the inputs. Same problem.  I imagine the solution looks something like this:

```
jQuery('input[id$=new]').attr('id').replace(/-new/,itemValue)
```

I just cannot figure out the syntax for this at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `.each()` ... the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) method accepts a function as the second parameter that returns the new value to be used as replacement

```
jQuery('label[for$=new]').attr('for', function(index, currentValue){
   return currentValue.replace(/-new/,'-' + itemValue);
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer to my question as asked.  All 3 answers are valid methods of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get the question, but something like:

```
var oldFor = $('label[for$=new]').attr('for');
var newFor = oldfor.replace(/-new/,itemValue);

$('label[for$=new]').attr('for', newFor);
```

> .attr( attributeName, value )
>
> ```
> attributeName = The name of the attribute to set.
> value = A value to set for the attribute.
> ```

When selecting multiple elements, you will need to iterate:

```
$('label[for$=new]').each(function(index) {
  $(this).attr('for', $(this).attr('for').replace(/-new/, '-' + itemValue));
});
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. It's probably because I still don't understand the syntax.  I get that you are creating a function which is executed for each iteration of the label.  What I don't get are the arguments being passed to the function (index and item).  index is never used in your example, and is item the label itself?  I'm going to look up how to use .each in jQuery and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Finally got this to work. I dropped the item parameter from the function, and used this instead of item inside the function.  The new code looks like jQuery('label[for$=new]'.each(function(index) { replacementText = '-' + itemValue; jQuery(this).attr('for',jQuery(this).attr('for').replace(/-new/,replacementText)); });

Comment: This works.  It's not quite as efficient as the answer using a nested function in the jQuery attr method, but it definitely works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I may, why not just put the `input` tag inside the `label` tag? That way, you won't need a `for` attribute inside the `label` tag.

Next, a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do would be to use the invoice ID number as the ID for the surrounding `div`, and add a 'new` class for "new" invoice entries.

So your form would look something like this:

```
<form id="InvoiceItemsForm-1" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']" method="post" name="InvoiceItemsForm-1" onsubmit="return false">   
    <div class="InvoiceItem new">   
        <label>New Invoice Item Number: <input class="InvoiceItemNumber" type="text" value="" name="InvoiceItemNumber"></label>   
        <label>Item Description: <input class="InvoiceItemDescription" type="text" value="" name="InvoiceItemDescription-new"></label>   
        <label for="InvoiceItemAmount-new">Item Amount: <input class="InvoiceItemAmount" type="text" value="" name="InvoiceItemAmount-new"></label>   
        <input id="addInvoiceItem-1" width="25" type="image" height="25" src="/payapp/images/greenplus.th.png" alt="Add New Invoice Item" onclick="addInvoiceItemButtonPushed(this)" value="invoiceItem">   
    </div>   
    <button id="CloseInvoice-1" onclick="closeInvoice(this)" type="button">Close Invoice</button>   
</form>
```

You'll still have all the targetability you need to get the new invoice item field data, but now, you only have two things to do to convert from a "new" invoice row to an "existing" invoice item row: add an `id` attribute to the `div` and remove the `new` class, both of which jQuery will let you do quite easily.

Comment: This is probably a good idea.  I'm still learning CSS selection, and I haven't assigned elements more than one class before.  I also did not know it was syntactically correct to put an input inside of a label instead of assigning the 'for' attribute.

Comment: This is definitely a good idea.  Simplifying the HTML simplifies the JavaScript/jQuery.  It doesn't answer my question as asked, but it is definitely helpful.

Comment: @chriv I wanted to post it as a comment, but I don't have that privilege yet.